# How do I store these values in localStorage?

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I'm putting together a very simple system that makes counting simple. I need these values to remain written in HTML after the page is reloaded, I just haven't learned how to manipulate the *localStorage API* yet.

Here is a self-explanatory and simplified executable example version of my code structure:

```js
    var total = window.document.getElementById('total')
    var debit = window.document.getElementById('debit')
    var credit = window.document.getElementById('credit')
    var somatotal = 0
    var somadebit = 0
    var somacredit = 0

    var valX = window.document.getElementById('valX')
    var valY = window.document.getElementById('valY')
    var valZ = window.document.getElementById('valZ')
    var somavalX = 0
    var somavalY = 0
    var somavalZ = 0

function addX() {
    var txtval = window.document.getElementById('txt-valX')
    var val = Number(txtval.value)
    var totalres = somatotal += val
    var totalval = somacredit += val
    total.innerText = totalres.toFixed(2)
    credit.innerText = totalval.toFixed(2)
    var valWay = somavalX += val
    valX.innerText = valWay.toFixed(2)
}
function addY() {
    var txtval = window.document.getElementById('txt-valY')
    var val = Number(txtval.value)
    var totalres = somatotal += val
    var totalval = somadebit += val
    total.innerText = totalres.toFixed(2)
    debit.innerText = totalval.toFixed(2)
    var valWay = somavalY += val
    valY.innerText = valWay.toFixed(2)
}
function addZ() {
    var txtval = window.document.getElementById('txt-valZ')
    var val = Number(txtval.value)
    var totalres = somatotal += val
    var totalval = somadebit += val
    total.innerText = totalres.toFixed(2)
    debit.innerText = totalval.toFixed(2)
    var valWay = somaY += val
    valY.innerText = valWay.toFixed(2)
}
```

```html
Balance 1:<div id="debit">0.00</div>
Balance 2<div id="credit">0.00</div>
TOTAL:<div id="total">0.00</div>
<br><br>

Value X:<div id="valX">0.00</div>
<input type="number" id="txt-valX" placeholder="vai add ao saldo 2">
<button onclick="addX()" id="bt0">OK</button><br>
Value Y:<div id="valY">0.00</div>
<input type="number" id="txt-valY" placeholder="vai add ao saldo 1">
<button onclick="addY()" id="bt1">OK</button><br>
Value Z:<div id="valZ">0.00</div>
<input type="number" id="txt-valZ" placeholder="vai add ao saldo 1">
<button onclick="addZ()" id="bt1">OK</button>
```

As you can see, I have **3** different values that will be added to **balance 1** or **balance 2**, which are displayed in HTML. Each value is also added together and the total is also displayed in HTML.
Now I need that the values are not lost when the page is restarted, being possible to continue to make the calculations starting from the way it was previously.

Can you help me?
I am grateful in advance.

Comment: `localStorage.setItem(key, value)` to save a value, and `localStorage.getItem(key)` to load a value.

Comment: @Chris I tried a lot, but I just don't understand the logic. Don't know where to put it or how to put it and it doesn't work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To save items in localStorage you have to use the next synthax:

```
localStorage.setItem('key','value')
```

To read the item in save it to a variable:

```
const variable = localStorage.getItem('key') // Remember it will be always an string
```

To remove:

```
localStorage.removeItem('key')
```

And finally to clear all items:

```
localStorage.clear()
```

You also could use sessionStorage, the difference is that while data in localStorage doesn't expire, data in sessionStorage is cleared when the page session ends.

---

Try to use this code:

```
// This part of the code render the localStorage values to HTML. If no value is stored so it just put a zero
total.innerHTML = Number(localStorage.getItem('total'))
debit.innerHTML = Number(localStorage.getItem('debit'))
credit.innerHTML = Number(localStorage.getItem('credit'))
valX.value = Number(localStorage.getItem('valX'))
valY.value = Number(localStorage.getItem('valY'))
valZ.value = Number(localStorage.getItem('valZ'))

// This function saves the texbox values to localStorage, and its called on every click. Please call this function on each click.
const saveValuesToLocalStorage => () {
    localStorage.setItem('total',total.textContent)
    localStorage.setItem('debit',debit.textContent)
    localStorage.setItem('credit',credit.textContent)
    localStorage.setItem('valX',valX.value)
    localStorage.setItem('valY',valY.value)
    localStorage.setItem('valZ',valZ.value)
}
```

For example, to call the function that saves the values to localStorage, call it inmediatelly into the add function:

```
function addX() {
    saveValuesToLocalStorage()
...
```

Comment: Thank you Andresmunozit. I don't know if it's bc I'm a very beginner or if it's bc my IQ is low, but I can’t understand, I’ve read a lot and I’ve tried a lot, but I can’t. Could you do it for me on jsFiddle? so I could observe and understand how it works in practice. the link: https://jsfiddle.net/y6g8afsv/

Comment: Sure, let me check. Spoiler alert, maybe you need to save the variables to localStorage on click event, and then, on page reload, try to recover that values if they exist in localStorage, if it doesn't exist, so set the variables to zero. You'll see.

Comment: I've added an example to my answer :) hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you so much! I didn't get it, but I'll keep trying here.

Comment: could you invite me on chat?

Comment: I realized that it is not enough to memorize what is expressed in the div, it is necessary that the current value of the variable is saved too, so that the calculations continue to work according to that current value. it's more complicated than I thought, I'd love a little help 

Comment: Sure, how can I start a chat? By the way, my suggestion was based on your code it's kind of messy. Anyways a good pattern is manage all the values into the JS logic, and update the HTML, only when an event happens.

Comment: I'm still a very beginner, I bet my code is repetitive and something. I just figured out how to open a chat by myself  here it is, hope it works for you there: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211511/chat

Answer (score 2):

You can use the localStorage API, and specifically, use the `setItem(key,value)`, and `getItem(key,value)` methods:

```
const myObj = {
  value1: 1,
}

// Set the items.  You can either do one key with the the value being an object that contains all of your values, or save each value under its own key.
localStorage.setItem('myUniqueKey',JSON.stringify(myObj));

// Later when you want to reload on refresh
localStorage.getItem('myUniqueKey');
```

More information can be found here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Comment: The second line should be `JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('myUniqueKey'))` otherwise it will be in string form.

Comment: Thank you Robert. I don't know if it's bc I'm a very beginner or if it's bc my IQ is low, but I can’t understand, I’ve read a lot and I’ve tried a lot, but I can’t. Could you do it for me on jsFiddle? so I could observe and understand how it works in practice. the link: https://jsfiddle.net/y6g8afsv/

Comment: I realized that it is not enough to memorize what is expressed in the div, it is necessary that the current value of the variable is saved too, so that the calculations continue to work according to that current value. it's more complicated than I thought, I'd love a little help 